# What is the IIS root directory on a remote server for a visual studio project

Tags: iis

I recently purchase a gaming website designed in VS 2015. 
The seller explained to point IIS to the published code's root which is:
C:\inetpub\production\folder-containing-published-code

There is also a virtual directory at:
C:\inetpub\persistentWebContent\production\

My home computer (Windows 7 Premium) runs the site fine via the browser. I needed to install IIS 7.5, .NET and other stuff.

The challenge now is to get it to work on my newly built remote server. This is a Win 2012 Server box with IIS 8.5 which by default already has a C:\inetpub directory set up. The test sites I set up via Plesk created a directory

C:\inetpub\vhosts

So where do I put my root directory??? And do I set it up from Remote Connection's IIS or through Plesk via browser??

Should I add web.Config as a default document in Plesk IIS settings since there isn't an index file for this project?

And do I specify Document Root in Plesk as well as in IIS??

I would believe IIS settings directly effect Plesk settings.

Suggestions please.

Comment: I suggest use Plesk control Panel for all the operations i.e. create new website (whcih will create new IIS website and will place it inside C:\inetpub\vhosts), upload published zip to the server etc. Just imagine you don't have Remote Desktop access to the server

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried putting the production files just under the domain name under vhosts (manually via FTP)  but the site would not launch. This is why I was tempted to proceed using Remote Connection. How will it know not to look for an INDEX file ? Would I need the directory holding the web.config file to be in httpdocs?

Comment: Did you try creating a new website using Plesk? Once website is created, go to HostSettings and check which folder website is mapped to. By default it is mapped to httpdocs. Just upload the published files under httpdocs folder using plesk file manager. Again using plesk is much more managed way of managing web apps.

Comment: I put all the 'published' files and sub folder directly into httpdocs, minus the virtual folders I still need to map (I'll need IIS at some point). Instead of seeing the default index page I now get a 'Runtime Error' . I did remove the default index.html file. I did not change anything in Plesk regarding the path/Document root . It is still httpdocs.

Comment: In your web.config under `system.web` put `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to see detailed error message.

Comment: It's very hard to explain what's going on when I change that line from on to off - so many errors that are similar to how the site ran with the final production database attached. I was supplied a staging db which always ran without errors and decided to add data to it and delete data older than a couple years. The errors I see with 'on' seem to not be accurate. Could I possibly hire you to look in to for me? My site runs fine locally, but no where else using all the same files and data. The connections string would be the only thing needing to be changed.

Comment: Ok, with setting to 'off' I'm getting SQL errors which is fine since I'm still uploading the database and have yet to attach it in SSMS. I'm hoping this will be the last concern. Thank you for all your assistance!

Comment: Thats great to know that you are moving forward :)

Comment: I'm uploading a 13GB database as I write this. I am going to try to get the site to run on my laptop, but I always seem to get an error when I test the binding settings.